# print a word or a given alphabets in reverse order using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Im new to Objective-C.
How to print a word or a given alphabets in reverse order using Objective-C?
what text i give in NSLog that should display in reverse order.
Exp: "Hello" should show "olleH".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
- (NSString *)reverseOfString : (NSString *)Str {
int strLength = (int)[Str length];
NSMutableString *reverseString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:strLength];
for(int i=strLength-1; i>=0; i--)
[reverseString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[Str characterAtIndex:i]]];
return reverseString;
```

}

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Or for a shorter recursive method(although inefficient for really long strings) but just so you have another way:

```
-(NSString *) reverseString: (NSString *) word{
    if([word length] == 1)
        return word;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[word substringWithRange: NSMakeRange([word length]-1,1)],[self reverseString:[word substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,[word length]-1)]]];
}
```

Comment: This is really inefficient — this allocates a new string for every substring along every step in the reversal. Also, if you get a long enough string, this will stack overflow because of the recursion. For a reverse operation link this, the iterative approach is the way to go.